# Keyboard mapping doesn't work as before

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I modified the keyboard mapping using `xkeycaps`, then i press the button to restore it but it doesn't work like before.. For example the cursor keys doesn't work. When i press the up cursor key while `xkeycaps` open, `xkeycaps` highlights the Print Screen key.

Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the `~/.xmodmap` file that xkeycaps generate, and the keyboard works as the beginning.